# Restart USB (ehci) in Fedora 14

Tags: linux, fedora, usb

I am looking for a way in Fedora 14 to restart the USB system so that all USB devices disconnect and reconnect to the OS (due to some slightly dubious USB peripherals that I have no choice but to use).

I found that one way is to use `modprobe` on ehci_hcd, but in Fedora ehci is built in. I found how to stop ehci by doing:

```
echo -n "0000:00:xx.x" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd/unbind
```

Where xx.x corresponds to the results of:

```
lspci|grep -i ehci
```

But I am not sure how to get it back up and running again. What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried to run that command to `bind` after `unbind`? `^un^`

Comment: if all else fails you can always recompile the kernel with the ehci built as a module